# Customer Create issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I am trying to creating customer with below code.

```
class Customer
{   
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $accountManagement;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $addressFactory;
    protected $customerInterfaceFactory;
    protected $encryptInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptInterface
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
        $this->addressFactory  = $addressFactory;
        $this->customerInterfaceFactory  = $customerInterfaceFactory;
        $this->encryptorInterface  = $encryptInterface;
    }

    public function customerUpdate {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId  = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        try{
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->setEmail('test@gmail.com'); 
            $customer->setFirstname('testname');
            $customer->setLastname('lastname');
            $customer->setPassword('123456');
            $customer->setData("custom_attribute",'Test'); 

            $customer->save();
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
            if($customerId > 1){
                $main_customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
                $main_customer ->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $main_customer ->setEmail('test123@gmail.com'); 
                $main_customer ->setFirstname('test1');
                $main_customer ->setLastname('last1');
                $main_customer ->setPassword('456789');
                $main_customer ->setData("custom_attribute",'Test1'); 

                $main_customer ->save();
                $main_customeId = $main_customer->getId();
            } 
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        } 
    }   
}
```

I am creating two customers with different data, both the customers are getting created but custom attribute for second customer is not saving.

Where i am wrong ? Please someone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

```
$main_customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
```

To call by Object Manager Instance

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$main_customer = objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
```

Then check result

Comment: Why it is like that? I am already injected the CustomerFactory class.

Comment: Anyway i checked it, its not working

Comment: $main_customer = $this->customerFactory->create(); you have already used this command, so you need refresh for create new customer factory

Comment: @Kein ,I am using like that only, so how it can be achieved?, can i inject same class with different variable?

Comment: Do you make sure code run after condition if($customerId > 1) ?

Comment: yes i have placed inside if condition, When i used your code, i am getting error call to method on null for setEmail()

Comment: Any log with your line print_r($e->getMessage()); ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82817/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-vu-tran-kien).